# getSummaryQty() is not working properly magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I used this function for `delete` cart items. It is working properly but

```
 $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');

 foreach ($itemProductArray as $itmeid => $productid) 
 {
        $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itmeid)->save();
 }
```

`getSummaryQty()` function gives old quantity value. Anyone help please?

Comment: When is the `getSummaryQty()` function called? I don't see it in your code sample.

Comment: i am telling about default getSummaryQty() everywhere in website except cart page it's reset autmatically

Comment: it seems to be issue with Ajax that's why product quantity is not updating on the spot.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit unclear, but I am assuming you need the getSummaryQty for a block, possibly the sidebar/minicart block or something similar.

If this is the case, make sure you have performed all of your quote modification functionality before the loadLayout() in the current controller, or at least before the block in question is initialized.

Alternatively but not really recommended is to refresh/redirect the page after the cart save.